# (C#) Access/Modify Objects in a List

Tags: c#, list, oop

New here, I've been learning c# for about a month.

Anyway, I've been searching StackOverflow for a couple of days now and couldn't find a specific answer to my problem...

```
//Here's my Class

public class Guy
{
     public static int ID { get; set; }
     public static int LifeExpectancy { get; set; }
     public static bool Living { get; set; }

     public Guy(int id, int lifeExpectancy, bool living)
     {
         ID = id;
         LifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy;
         Living = living;
     }
}
```

**What I'm trying to do is create a specific number of "someGuy" objects to   then put them into a public list using this method...**

```
public static List<Guy> Guys = new List<Guy>();

public static void makeSomeGuys(int howManyGuys)
{
    for (int i = 0, i <= howManyGuys; i++)
    {
        int id = i;
        int lifeExpectancy = 80;
        bool alive = true;

        Guys.Add(New Guy(id, lifeExpectancy, alive));

        Console.WriteLine("Made a new Guy {0}", id);         
    }
    return; 
}
```

Questions in order of importance:

**How do I access a specific object as well as its parameters?** *(Accessing from the list "Guys".)*

**How do I access an object from this list in another class?** *(Not that I absolutely need to, I'm curious)*

**Can I search for an object in a list by using its parameters?** *(As opposed to doing something like... `humanPopulation[number]`)*

**Should I create a new list for objects that have had their parameters modified?** *(As opposed to leaving it in the original list)*

**Is it possible to remove items from a list?** *(Just in general, is that a thing people do? if so, why?)*

*I really only need the first question answered. The rest of them are just a bonus. Thanks!*

Comment: Have you read the API documentation for `List`?  Here's a link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace test
{
    public class Guy
    {
        private int m_ID;
        private int m_LifeExpectancy;
        private bool m_Living;

        public int ID
        {
            get { return m_ID; }
            set { m_ID = value; }
        }
        public int LifeExpectancy
        {
            get { return m_LifeExpectancy; }
            set { m_LifeExpectancy = value; }
        }
        public bool Living
        {
            get { return m_Living; }
            set { m_Living = value; }
        }

        public Guy(int id, int lifeExpectancy, bool living)
        {
            ID = id;
            LifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy;
            Living = living;
        }
    }

    public class MyFactory
    {
        public IList<Guy> MakeSomeGuys(int howManyGuys)
        {

            IList<Guy> localGuys = new List<Guy>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= howManyGuys; i++)
            {

                int id = i;
                int lifeExpectancy = 80;
                bool alive = true;

                localGuys.Add(new Guy(id, lifeExpectancy, alive));

                Console.WriteLine("Made a new Guy {0}", id);
            }


            return localGuys;
        }
    }

    public class program
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            MyFactory mf = new MyFactory();
            IList<Guy> guys = mf.MakeSomeGuys(5);

            //How do I access a specific object as well as its parameters? (Accessing from the list "Guys".)
            int GetFirstGuyId = guys.FirstOrDefault().ID; //LEARN LINQ

            //How do I access an object from this list in another class? (Not that I absolutely need to, I'm curious)
            //you need to learn about object oriented encapsulation for better understanding.

            //Can I search for an object in a list by using its parameters? (As opposed to doing something like...humanPopulation[number])
            Guy guyById = guys.Where(g => g.ID == 5).FirstOrDefault(); // returns the first match (need to learn lambda expression)

            //Should I create a new list for objects that have had their parameters modified? (As opposed to leaving it in the original list)
            // you need to learn about passing values by value / reference (by reference you already changing the original!).

            //Is it possible to remove items from a list? (Just in general, is that a thing people do? if so, why?)
            //yes
            guys.Remove(guyById);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first question can be : int firstGuyLifeExpectancy = guys[0].LifeExpectancy;

Comment: I don't understand the uppermost part of the code you wrote, the part when you correct my Improper encapsulation. is there a difference to doing it the way you do it? Or is it just proper?

Comment: In that way you can control your input/output get/set for example set value only if it bigger then zero and so on...

Comment: And 'value' is whatever the return value of m_ID is, right? If so then I understand completely, and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, when you use set the value is what you passing to the property and setting the m_ID and the get is the return of m_ID value, you welcome.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to remove the **static** modifier from the properties of the Guy class, i.e.:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public int LifeExpectancy { get; set; }
public bool Living { get; set; }
```

because static causes the property to be an attribute of the class itself, rather than the instances of the class (the individual 'guys').

To access life expectancy of the first guy (the zeroth):

```
Console.WriteLine(Guys[0].LifeExpectancy);
```

To access life expectancy of the fifth guy:

```
Console.WriteLine(Guys[4].LifeExpectancy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely new to C# and OO programming, so I've included some good links in this answer.

**Regarding question 1 only:**

Firstly, your `Guy` class properties aren't properly encapsulated.  Make sure you properly scope the `ID`, `LifeExpectancy` and `Living` properties like shown in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) article.

If you'd like to access a *specific* item, that is, a `Guy` with a particular ID, you'd be better off using an associative container like [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you're happy with the `List` container, you need to use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) method on `Guys` as shown in the example at the link.  You'll notice the term *Predicate* in the documentation, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) link will elaborate.